# how does hibernate do the caching mechanism, what is difference between first level cache and second level cache

Tags: hibernate

How does the hibernate cache mechanism work?

What is the requirement of caching and when do we need second level caching?

I know how to get that, but I need to get real time issues and scenarios where we can get that.

Comment: "How does the hibernate cache mechanism work?" - when an Entity is being loaded and cacheable, the Entity Manager stores the object in its cache using the Entities primary key as cache key to prevent further accesses through the Entity Manager from repeatedly accessing the database and returning the serialized object instead.
"What is the requirement of caching" - please look up the internet for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of broad.

How does the hibernate cache mechanism work ?

Ans - It works with help of session/session factory depending on level of cache.Session/Session factory holds value of entity object and which is mapped with its primary key.It prevent us for making lesser db hits in db for same object(i.e. with same primary key or id).

What is the requirement of caching and when do we need second level caching?

Ans - As told above, it helps in improving performance. Lesser db hits more performance.First level cache is applicable to single session.It's default cache.

When we require if an entity needs to be shared between different session from a same session factory, we use second level cache.
you can read more [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm)

Answer (score 0):

**It's useful when:**

```
You read-write database only via Hibernate because the second level cache is invalidated / updated per entity when an entity is updated/deleted via hibernate. It is not invalidated if the database is updated in a different way. If you are using query use query cache otherwise it will not work for query.
```

Answer (score 0):

First-level cache always Associates with the Session object. Hibernate uses this cache by default. Here, it processes one transaction after another one, means wont process one transaction many times. Mainly it reduces the number of SQL queries it needs to generate within a given transaction. That is instead of updating after every modification done in the transaction, it updates the transaction only at the end of the transaction.

Second-level cache always associates with the Session Factory object. While running the transactions, in between it loads the objects at the Session Factory level, so that those objects will be available to the entire application, not bound to single user. Since the objects are already loaded in the cache, whenever an object is returned by the query, at that time no need to go for a database transaction. In this way the second level cache works. Here we can use query level cache also. Later we will discuss about it.